# Where to set a property in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, properties, uiviewcontroller

A rather basic question I'm unsure about. I typically set up my `UIViewController`'s view-related code in `viewDidLoad`. If the controller has some properties for labels, etc, this is where I would initialize them and add them to the view. These properties are usually declared in the .m so can be considered pseudo-private.

However - if the controller exposes one of these properties (let's say a `UILabel`) in its header file, I am finding that I can't rely on it existing when it comes time to set it up. For example:

```
CustomViewController *controller = [CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
controller.someLabel.text = @"label text goes here";
//then comes the presentation code
```

I find that I am setting the label's text too early - `viewDidLoad` has not fired yet so the label is nil.

Should I create this label in `init` and add it in `viewDidLoad`? Should I be doing all my set up in `init`? Or maybe all the initialization of view properties? Or judge it on a case by case basis?

Or maybe the root cause is that I shouldn't have a controller exposing a view (the label) and use some other pattern?

I'm looking for a consistent way to structure my code.

Comment: If it has to be ready by the time viewDidLoad fires, then it would be fine to set it in the initializer since that occurs before viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yeah, I just feel icky doing it one way sometimes and another way other times. Guess I should be more pragmatic.

Comment: Where would you be trying to call that code you have in your question? From another controller? If so, you need to pass the string to a string property in CustomController, and have it set its label's text in viewDidLoad. It's better from an MVC standpoint to have the controller populate its own UI, so passing in the data you need to do that is the correct way..

Comment: Something else you can do is to create the label on-demand in the property getter.  Then the caller can be guaranteed a label, then you simply size it and add to view in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: @rdelmar - thank you, my suspicion was along those lines. Yes I am setting the property from another controller. I could tell something was off. I guess if it was a view, not a controller, it would be ok (e.g. cell.textlabel etc)? Secondly, would I then override the setter for that string to update the label?

Comment: I'm not sure about the context of what you're talking about with a view instead of a view controller. If the view is in the same controller that's setting the label's text, then that would be ok. You could override the setter, I don't know if that's any better than just  saying myView.label.text = ...

Comment: I was thinking of something like a UITableViewCell, which exposes all of it's subviews (e.g. textLabel and detailTextLabel). It doesn't have you set a 'labelString' or similar as you suggest. I'm trying to understand the distinction and if its an MVC thing - mine is a controller, the cell is a view. Also, without overriding the setter, it feels very inconsistent. In fact i'd rather not expose the label at all. Otherwise I have to remember to always set the string if its before the view loads, but optionally set either one after. Seems complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all your concerns. Exposing subviews to your superview (the cell) is different from exposing a label in one controller to another controller. A view needs to be able to talk directly to its superviews, but one controller doesn't necessarily need to know about another controller's views. I think, for reasons of encapsulation, it's better to pass the data into another controller that it need to work (maybe even in its init method), than to control it's views from another controller.

Comment: but just to be sure, had you wanted you *were* able to set the `someLabel` directly. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you are pretty much right already. The thing is, all views components of your controller are not loaded until the view is actually presented. So you cannot set anything of your IBOutlets from outside the controller.

One approach for passing, for example, a text for an UILabel, it's create a new string property, let's say `self.myString`, assign it from outside, and in your viewDidLoad, set in the labels' text this property.

```
CustomViewController *controller = [CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
controller.myString = @"label text goes here";
```

And inside the `CustomViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    (...)
    self.label.text = self.myString;
}
```

Comment: And would I need a customer setter also? Since otherwise [controller setMyString:] won't update the textfield.

Comment: I don't think so. This auxiliary property it's only necessary and used in this case, where the viewController is allocated but not presented yet. In my example, the text is already set in the `viewDidLoad`, so you wouldn't need the custom setter. If you want to change the text of the label again somewhere else outside the class, after the view was presented, you would be able to use the IBOutlet directly.

Comment: But then I have to remember to use one property if its before the view loads (the string), and another if its after (the label directly) (i'm doing all of this in code too so no outlets).

Comment: Yeah, at this level it's just a matter of code design, you can do what you want. You can, for example, create a method like `setText:` and inside do something like `if (self.label) {self.label.text = text;} else {self.myString.text = text;}` and then only use this method. It will work after and before the initializing of the outlets

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do something like the following, which works for me if I only want to update the view on demand (if I want to update it more frequently then I would do so in `viewWillAppear` or via `KVO` or some other notification mechanism).

Have some private method that does my UI setup based on the property:

```
- (void)_updateUIForProperty {
    // Handle UI update
}
```

Implement a setter for my public property that calls the `_updateUIForProperty` method if the view has been loaded already:

```
- (void)setProperty:(<#property type#>)property {
    _property = property;

    if(self.isViewLoaded) {
        [self _updateUIForProperty];
    }
}
```

And then to handle the case where the property was set prior to the view loading, we do something like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Other initialization

    if(_property != nil) {
        [self _updateUIForProperty];
    }
}
```